# How to pass a method as parameter?

Tags: c++, methods

Having this class :

```
class Automat
{
private:
    // some members ... 
public:
    Automat();
    ~Automat();
    void addQ(string& newQ) ; 
    void addCharacter(char& newChar)  ;
    void addLamda(Lamda& newLamda) ; 
    void setStartSituation(string& startQ) ; 
    void addAccQ(string& newQ) ;
    bool checkWord(string& wordToCheck) ; 
    friend istream& operator >> (istream &isInput, Automat &newAutomat);
    string& getSituation(string& startSituation) ; 
};
```

And also  class called  `Menu` which has the follow method  :

```
void Menu::handleStringSituations(string &stringOfSituation , Automat* autoToHandle ,void (Automat::*methodToDo) () )
{
    // some code ...
      (*autoToHandle).*methodToDo() ; 
}
```

The line   `(*autoToHandle).*methodToDo() ;` gives an error  .

As you can see I trying to pass any method from `Automat` class as a parameter to `handleStringSituations` method with no success.

Comment: I'd probably suggest a redesign. If you describe your goals (rather than your attempts at achieving them) we could take a look. Some might suggest `std::function`, but I think you're probably not going about this the right way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you try to do is usually known as closure, a concept strong in functional programming. Rather than reinventing the wheel, I suggest you look into Boost::Phoenix, which provides this in a nice, peer reviewed library.

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/phoenix/doc/html/index.html

However, since C++ is a statically typed language, you will have to do some marshalling. There is no such thing like a generic function (object) in C++.

Answer (score 3):

How would you call it? C++ is not a dynamically typed language; it is statically typed. Therefore, everything you call must have a specific set of parameters, and each parameter must be typed. There's no way to call "some function" with some number of parameters and hope that it can be sorted out at runtime.

You need a specific interface. `methodToDo` needs to have some kind of interface; without one, you cannot call it.

The best you might be able to do is to have multiple versions of `handleStringSituations`, where each one takes a different member pointer type:

```
void handleStringSituations(string &stringOfSituation , Automat* autoToHandle ,void (Automat::*methodToDo) ()) ;
void handleStringSituations(string &stringOfSituation , Automat* autoToHandle ,void (Automat::*methodToDo) (string&)) ;
void handleStringSituations(string &stringOfSituation , Automat* autoToHandle ,void (Automat::*methodToDo) (Lamda&)) ;
```

Comment: Isn't it possible to pass a `void*` which can then be cast to any desired signature?  A reference to a function is just a pointer, after all.

Comment: @aroth: Member pointers are not the same thing a regular pointers. And casting function pointers to `void*` is undefined behavior anyway (thought it generally works). Casting member pointers to `void*` almost never works, since member pointers are rarely the same size or type as a regular pointer.

Comment: @Nicol Bolas: How so? Could you please provide some examples?

Comment: @vines: Check http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/FastDelegate.aspx for an in-depth analysis. The article is from 2004, but the fundamental issues remain the same.