# How to use pointer to method as a parameter (when pointer to function is required)?

Tags: c++, function, pointers, methods, function-pointers

I have some 3rd-part code:

```
class A(){
    public:
        void assingOnClickFunction(void (*function)(); 
};
```

I cannot change **anything** in that code.
I want to pass to that `A::assingOnClickFunction()` my method of class B, `void B::someFunction()`. I have tried (all **inside** of the B class!):

```
a->assingOnClickFunction(this->someFunction);
```

But I get the error:

> function call missing argument list; use '&B::someFunction' to create
>   a pointer to member

So I have changed it to:

```
a->assingOnClickFunction(&B::someFunction);
```

But now there is ofc the error about the different types: `(void(*)()` and `(&B::*)()`

I cannot make `B::someFunction()` static (it uses a lot of non-static `B`'s members and methods)!

So, **is there an option to pass my** `B::someFunction()` **to the** `A::assingOnClickFunction()`, not changing it to static and not changing anything in `A` class (`A` is not and cannot be aware of `B`, `B` includes `A`)**?**

Comment: Is the member function you want to pass `static`?

Comment: As I have wrote, it's not static and I cannot change it to static.

Comment: Trying it gives an error: 'type cast' : cannot convert from 'void (__thiscall B::* )(void)' to 'void *'

Comment: Please google before asking - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6852462/how-to-pass-a-method-as-parameter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the member function you want to pass is not `static`, you cannot do that. The method in `A` accepts a function pointer to a function with no arguments, and a non-static member function has an implicit `this` pointer argument.

Answer (score 2):

In order to call a (non-static) method of an object, you need to know both the object and the method to call.

The assingOnClickFunction() function only takes a pointer to a function, so you cannot pass it the needed information.

Besides some horrible hacks, like implementing a function that has access to some global instance of your object, and calls the method throught that,  it can't be done.

Comment: Indeed, I was thinking about something like that 'hacks'. But I guess I should rebuild my code and make it in some other way (it would looks really horrible with global instances and functions with access to it).

Answer (score 1):

A pointer to member function is **not** a pointer to function. If you have a function that takes an argument whose type is pointer-to-function, you **cannot** call it with a pointer to member function.